# find error total amount total 31049 35% =2572.3

Tags: math

### find error total amount   total 31049   35% =2572.3

```
    amount  %   total   
--------------------------------    
        5990    12% =718.8
        4999    10% =499.9
        5060    6%  =303.6
        15000   7%  =1050
--------------------------------
total   31049   35% =2572.3
--------------------------------
but =   31049   35%  =10867.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically you cant add percentages as you did as you are taking portions of something, but some of them are bigger than the others.
A simple way of seeing it is applying the same logic but using 100% if you add 4 times 100% it would be 4 times the original value!

Another way to see percentages is to view them add fractions like 50% is X/2 or 33% is X/3 this way you can remember that the only way to add fractions is to have a common multiple of them (commonly the minimum common multiple) after finding it then you can add fractions.